# Using AMPScript to fill SubscriberKey in Smart Capture Form in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, form, smart-capture

I know I may be asking something very basic but I can´t get it to work.
I'm trying to fill the SubscriberKey field in the SmartCapture form with no success.
What I'm trying to do is use a Concat formula tu fill the SubsriberKey with a prefix, ex:

```
%%[VAR @SubscriberKey, @EmailAddress
set @EmailAddress = %%emailaddr%%
set @SubscriberKey= %%=Concat(="TEST_", @EmailAddress)%%
]%%

]%%
```

[image]

Is there something wrong with the code?
Is this the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need the `%%` signs inside of an AMPscript block. This is the correct synthax:

```
%%[
VAR @SubscriberKey, @EmailAddress 
set @EmailAddress = emailaddr
set @SubscriberKey = Concat('TEST_', @EmailAddress)
]%%
```

But you don't actually need the above block - you pass the value in a hidden form field if you just include the following inline AMPscript string in there:

```
%%=v(Concat('TEST_', emailaddr))=%%
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I used the HIDDEN ATTIBUTE option you mention
I get the same issue I had before with another code, I only get the SubscriberKey to be "TEST_"

Comment: How do you test it? From an email?

Comment: No, going yo the link and filling the SmartCapture

Comment: Btw, If you want it to pull the email address from the email typed into the form, you need to use the name of the column used in the target Data Extension. `emailaddr` is a personalization string and it takes the email address of the subscriber that the email with the link to this CloudPages was sent to.

Comment: Here’s how to test in a Subscriber context: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_perform_subscriber_preview_test_send.htm&type=5